# Oracle regex - does not start with and does not end with

Tags: regex, oracle

The following Oracle regular expressions do not work and I don't know why.

"Does not start with '*abc*'":

```
^[^(abc)]
```

"Does not end with '*abc*'":

```
[^(abc)]$
```

The problem is that the Oracle regex engine does not seem to recognize the 'abc' string as a unit, but only is looking at the letters individually. The parentheses () are supposed to create a string unit. So I don't know what is going on. I used the square brackets only because I believe the 'not' operator ^ only operates inside the brackets, otherwise the ^ is recognized as start of line.

For reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm

Comment: try: ([^A].*|.[^B].*|..[^C].*)

Comment: @parzival aabbcc does not work for your regex, and I think it should work for the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing for non-matching like this can get complicated, so I'd recommend testing for a match and negating the result.

Does not start with `abc`:

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(myString, '^abc')
```

Does not end with `abc`:

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(myString, 'abc$')
```

---

As for why it doesn't work, as @DavidKnipe says in his answer: it's because you're using character classes. The regex `^[^(abc)]` parses out like this:

- The first `^` says "anchor to the beginning of the string"
- The `[^(abc)]` is a character class that says "match any *single* character as long as it's not `(` or `a` or `b` or `c` or `)`".

Answer (score 0):

The `^` operator for negation is only for character classes. But you shouldn't be using character classes. I don't know whether Oracle regexes allow lookaround operations (lookahead and lookbehind). If they do, use `^(?!abc)` and `(?<!abc)$`.

Comment: They don't... unfortunately.