# regex: find strings that do not begin with a certain prefix

Tags: regex, grep

I want to find a word in strings, but only if it **doesn't begin with a prefix**.

for example.

I'd like to find all the appearances of APP_PERFORM_TASK, but only if they are not starting with a prefix of CMD_DO("

so,

```
CMD_DO("APP_PERFORM_TASK")   <- OK (i don't need to know about this)  
BLAH("APP_PERFORM_TASK")     <-- NOT OK, this should match my search.
```

I tried:

```
(?!CMD_DO\(")APP_PERFORM_TASK
```

But that doesn't produce the results I need. What I doing wrong?

Comment: What language / engine?

Comment: I'm just looking for the regex expression. nothing particular.

Comment: But what you have appears to work: http://rubular.com/r/eKNxWoSLf8

Comment: And alternatively, possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899422/regular-expression-for-a-string-that-does-not-start-with-a-sequence), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095580/oracle-regex-does-not-start-with-and-does-not-end-with), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116328/regexp-matching-string-not-starting-with-my), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string) ...

Comment: @ExplosionPills Lol, add the `i` flag and see what happens ;)

Comment: @RM1970 It's important to know the language or engine of the regex, because different ones support different features. For instance, the negative lookbehind is not always supported.

Comment: Perhaps that's why. Let's concentrate on command line tool grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick way:

Use the --invert-match (also known as -v) flag to ignore CMD_DO and pipe the results to a second grep that only matches BLAH:

```
grep -v CMD_DO dummy | grep BLAH
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing NegativeLookAhead `(?!)` with NegativeLookBehind `(?<!)` in your regex

```
(?<!CMD_DO\(")APP_PERFORM_TASK
```

Check this in action [here](http://regex101.com/r/oS0uF4)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment: `Let's concentrate on command line tool grep`

Here is `grep` solution without using `-P` switch (perl like regex):

```
grep 'APP_PERFORM_TASK' file | grep -v '^CMD_DO("'
```

Here is `grep` solution using `-P` switch and `negative lokbehind`:

```
grep -P '(?<!^CMD_DO\(")APP_PERFORM_TASK' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?!CMD_DO\(").*APP_PERFORM_TASK.*
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle an input line with both the desirable and undesirable forms like:

```
CMD_DO("APP_PERFORM_TASK") BLAH("APP_PERFORM_TASK")
```

you'd need something like this in awk (using GNU awk for gensub()):

```
awk -v s="APP_PERFORM_TASK" 'gensub("CMD_DO\\(\\""s,"","") ~ s' file
```

i.e. get rid of all of the unwanted occurrences of the string then test whats left.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version

```
awk '/APP_PERFORM_TASK/ && !/^CMD_DO/' file
```